# SIGEXIT in solaris

Tags: oracle, signals, solaris-10

I had a program issue which have the following pstack output.

```
 6600:   ora_d006_LOOKUP
 ffffffff7addbbd0 __systemcall6 (3, ffffffff7d300440, 0, ffffffff7adc1268, d, fff7) + 24
 ffffffff7adcba74 pthread_sigmask (2000, 0, 0, 0, ffffffff7d300200, d) + 1c4
 00000001068ff3bc sslssalck (ffffffff7fffb138, 2, ffffffff7fffb070, 0, 3e8, 10c24d7e0) + 7c
 00000001069358e8 sltmarm (a00029810, 29810, 10c3f3ab0, 3f9, a00000000, 29810) + 88
 00000001069aa734 ltmdvp (8006689e, 3f9, 0, 10c55ba38, 10c3f8160, 10c3f34d0) + 154
 00000001068ff2a4 sslsstehdlr (e, 0, ffffffff7fffb570, 7fffff84, 10c3ed0d8, 10c24d7e0) + 224
 ffffffff7add7498 __sighndlr (e, 0, ffffffff7fffb570, 1068fcba0, 0, d) + c
 ffffffff7adcb02c call_user_handler (ffffffff7d300200, ffffffff7d300200, ffffffff7fffb570, c, 0, 0) + 3e0
 ffffffff7adcb238 sigacthandler (0, 0, ffffffff7fffb570, ffffffff7d300200, 0, ffffffff7af3e000) + 68
 --- called from signal handler with signal 0 (SIGEXIT) ---
 ffffffff7addad48 ioctl (10c3f80c0, bb8, 400, 10c426810, 10c6aae90, 2001420c) + c
 0000000109e47668 nteveque (10c40c940, bb8, ffffffff7fffca98, 1afbfb85a4, 1c, 98) + 28
 0000000109e3f0c0 ntevque (7, bb8, 10c2cbfd0, 10c40c940, ffffffff7fffca98, 10c2cbfd0) + 80
 0000000109d8e738 nsevwait (0, 0, 10c25cc00, 0, 10c25cc04, 10c3f7a60) + 1b8
 000000010092e7b4 ksnwait (10c25cc00, 6, 10c403fb0, 10c25c000, 10c25c, 10c000) + 54
 000000010072060c ksliwat (0, ffffffff7fffd8e8, 1770, 10c25b, 10c000, 0) + 140c
 0000000100704b28 kslwait (1770, ffffffff7fffd8e8, ffffffff7fffd8e8, ffffffff7fffd8e8, 0, 0) + e8
 00000001065707a0 kmdmai (1b1bfffe00, 10c2628e8, 1b02faf258, 10c26c190, 10c25b, 38000d000) + e40
 00000001063b0400 opirip (10a726000, 0, 380002, 380000, 38002a000, 38002a) + a80
 00000001035c59cc opidrv (32, 4, ffffffff7ffff590, 1ebb90, ffffffff7af45050, ffffffff7ffff9a0) + 30c
 000000010474117c sou2o (ffffffff7ffff568, 32, 4, ffffffff7ffff590, 10c000, 10b800) + 5c
 0000000100604f64 opimai_real (3, ffffffff7ffff838, ffffffff7ffffb60, ffffffff7ffffbb5, 0, 0) + 204
 0000000104757380 ssthrdmain (10c000, 3, 44dc00, 100604d60, 10c27c000, 10c27c) + 140
 0000000100604c74 main (3, ffffffff7ffff948, 0, ffffffff7ffff840, ffffffff7ffff950, ffffffff7d300200) + 134
 0000000100604b1c _start (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 17c
```

this process is used to dispatch request from client. During the issue, no more request can be sent in and this process consumed many SYS cpu.

I guess the issue started with "signal handler with signal 0 (SIGEXIT)"
 After some google,  I found SIGEXIT is not a common SIGNAL. many people said it is a pseudo signal.
 [How do I trap EXIT in a solaris 11 shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516291/how-do-i-trap-exit-in-a-solaris-11-shell-script)

But how can I set up a signal handle for this "pseudo" signal with c/c++ on solaris? 
 how can I make the program have the following output?

```
  ...  my_handle_signal .... 
  --- called from signal handler with signal 0 (SIGEXIT) ---
  ... xxxx
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ioctl prototype in solaris libc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194215/ioctl-prototype-in-solaris-libc)

Comment: zhihuifan, please do not open additional questions, just add new details to already created one.

Comment: zhihuifan, is your program named "Oracle"? You should contact your support manager in Oracle to do search in Oracle bug database. It will almost be impossible to debug the unknown version of closed-source program remotely by using this forum and by not paying for it.

Comment: hi osgx.  Yes, it is Oracle database dispatch process.  we have contacted with oracle support for this issue around 1 years.  but still don't resolve this.   Oracle support usually not oracle developer, and the communication is not very smooth.  so I want to ask some program developer to help debug this problem and sent more information to oracle support. I hope we can resolve this issue earlier.    Really appreciate your help about this.